# Get a variable from database based on another query

Tags: php, mysql

I have no idea what I am doing.

In my code I get a csv list of my categories which are nested. I want to add the name of parent category to each csv line.

Like if I am getting category_name, category_parent_id, category_image and so on

I want to do another search in the category_description table and find category_name that matches the category_id to the parent_id that I got before
I have commented out the lines that I am having problem with

```html
<?php
DEFINE ('DBUSER', 'myosjrjp_osco638'); 
DEFINE ('DBPW', 'plS]q4)U78'); 
DEFINE ('DBHOST', 'localhost'); 
DEFINE ('DBNAME', 'myosjrjp_osco638'); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL | E_ALL); 
 
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPW);
if (!$dbc) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
    exit();
}

$dbs = mysqli_select_db($dbc, DBNAME);
if (!$dbs) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
    exit(); 
}

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, "SHOW COLUMNS FROM categories");
$numberOfRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($numberOfRows > 0) {

/* By changing Fred below to another specific persons name you can limit access to just the part of the database for that individual. You could eliminate WHERE recorder_id='Fred' all together if you want to give full access to everyone. */

$values = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT categories.categories_id, categories.categories_image, categories.parent_id, categories_description.categories_id, categories_description.language_id, categories_description.categories_name, categories_description.categories_description
FROM categories
JOIN categories_description
WHERE categories.categories_id = categories_description.categories_id ");
while ($rowr = mysqli_fetch_row($values)) {
 for ($j=0;$j<$numberOfRows;$j++) {
  /////////
//  $parent= mysqli_fetch_row($values,'categories.parent_id');
//  $values2 = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT categories_name, 
//FROM categories_description
//WHERE categories_id = '$parent'");
  //////

  $csv_output .= $rowr[$j].", ";
 // $csv_output .= $values2('categories_name').", ";
 }
 $csv_output .= "\n";
}

}

print $csv_output;
exit;
?>
```

Comment: *"i have no idea what i am doing"* - Which makes it hard for us to know what the question's about really. What's "not" working here?

Comment: and seems related to your other question earlier http://stackoverflow.com/q/40289135/ - Please don't repost; edit your other question with any added information.

Answer (score 0):

Easily you can make a csv directly using a mysql query with anything you wants . Using into out file function of mysql. You can join 2 tables also with this using UNION ALL you can put heading for each column. Also you can get data from another table inside the query using select * from table mane where table I'd = your present table I'd. Anything you can customize with that query. Also it will be very fast . Search mysql INTO OUTFILE

See the query in the example in the answer here [How to add headers in CSV when using into out file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40236872/how-to-add-headers-in-csv-when-using-into-out-file/40238457#40238457). :